# TypeError: GridSizer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: wxpython, typeerror

I would like to display a table of 6 buttons(cancel,delete,save,quit,stop,new), with 3 rows and 2 colunms.
I tried to run this program below, but it did not work.

```
import wx

class Identifiers(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(200, 150))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        grid = wx.GridSizer(3, 2)

        grid.AddMany([(wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_CANCEL), 0, wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, 9),
        (wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_DELETE), 0, wx.TOP, 9),
        (wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_SAVE), 0, wx.LEFT, 9),
        (wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_EXIT)),
        (wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_STOP), 0, wx.LEFT, 9),
        (wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_NEW))])

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)

        panel.SetSizer(grid)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

app = wx.App()
Identifiers(None, -1, '')
app.MainLoop()
```

This is the whole message error.

```
File "C:/Python34/Test_wxPython/Events/Identifiers.py", line 12, in __init__
    grid = wx.GridSizer(3, 2)
TypeError: GridSizer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: not enough arguments
  overload 2: argument 2 has unexpected type 'int'
  overload 3: not enough arguments
  overload 4: not enough arguments
```

There is a problem with this line `grid = wx.GridSizer(3, 2)`, but I do not manage to figure out the problem.

Comment: What is your wxpython version?, In 3.0.2 works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running Python 3.4 I presume you are using wxPython Phoenix. According to the documentation [of `wx.GridSizer`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GridSizer.html) two `int` do not match any of the allowed signatures. Use e.g. three integers instead.

**EDIT**: Link has slightly changed.

Comment: link is broken.